# Pip won't install anything [Could Not Install Packages Due To An Environment Error]

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Any time I try and install a new package via `pip install [package_name]` using Anaconda I get this error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\nick\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.7.3.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

Comment: have you tried the `user` flag?

Comment: I just tried it. It results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the package with `conda`:

```
conda install python-dateutil
```